# GWT ListBox rendering different across browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, gwt, listbox

So, I have a custom implementation of ListBox for a GWT application

Its xml code looks like this:

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="{style.yearRangePanel}">
        <g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="{style.rangeSeparator} {style.paddingTop}">
            <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.horizontalAlign}" ui:field="integerRangeDropdownLabel">Filter studies by range of enroled patients: </g:Label>
            <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.prefixSpace} {style.horizontalAlign}" ui:field="startSampleSizeLabel"/>
        </g:FlowPanel>
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="integerRangeDropdownFilterPanel" addStyleNames="{style.yearRangeSliderPanel} {style.paddingTop}">
            <g:ListBox ui:field ="integerRangeDropdownListBox" styleName="{style.customListBox}"/>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:FlowPanel>
```

And its main java code looks like:

```
 @UiConstructor
    public IntegerRangeDropdownFilterComposite (String fieldName, String labelText){
        this.initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        filterChangedEvent = new FilterChangedEvent(fieldName);

        FilterConfig filterConfig = clientFactory.getApplicationContext().getConfig(FilterConfig.class);
        List<FilterSetting> filterSettings = filterConfig.getFilterConfigBy(fieldName);
        FilterSetting filterSetting = filterSettings.get(0);
        filterByIntegerRangeSettings = (FilterConfig.FilterByIntegerRangeSettings) filterSetting;

        this.increment = Integer.toString(filterByIntegerRangeSettings.getIncrement());
        this.minSampleSize = Integer.toString(filterByIntegerRangeSettings.getInitialValue());
        this.maxSampleSize = Integer.toString(filterByIntegerRangeSettings.getEnd());

        this.setupConfig(fieldName);
    }

    private void setupConfig(String fieldName){
        setupRange(fieldName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        integerRangeDropdownFilterPanel.add((Widget) integerRangeDropdownListBox);
    }

    public void resetIntegerRangeDropdownFilter() {
        filterChangedEvent.resetField();
    }

    @UiHandler("integerRangeDropdownListBox")
    public void clickEnroled(ChangeEvent changeEvent){
        if(integerRangeDropdownListBox.getSelectedIndex()!=0) {
            String selectedItem = integerRangeDropdownListBox.getSelectedItemText();
            minSampleSize = selectedItem.substring(0, (selectedItem.indexOf('-'))).trim();
            maxSampleSize = selectedItem.substring((selectedItem.indexOf('-') + 1)).trim();
        }
        else{
            minSampleSize="0";
            maxSampleSize="100000";
        }
        resetIntegerRangeDropdownFilter();
        filterChangedEvent.addFilter(Integer.parseInt(minSampleSize), Integer.parseInt(maxSampleSize));
        clientFactory.getEventBus().fireEvent(filterChangedEvent);
    }
```

Now, as for the style, I've tried "bootstrapping" it with this line:

```
<g:ListBox ui:field ="integerRangeDropdownListBox" styleName="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"/>
```

And I've tried customizing it with CSS like this:

```
.customListBox{
            background-color: dodgerblue !important;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
        }

   <g:ListBox ui:field ="integerRangeDropdownListBox" styleName="{style.customListBox}"/>
```

Whichever way I do it, it will not render equally across browsers, it only looks "nice" on Google Chrome, while in Safari and Firefox it will have an "uglee" arrow for the  dropdown and different scroll bar.

Any ideas as for why this may be happening?  Needless to say I've tried google and the forum, but searching for GWT related topics is pretty much useless

[image: Firefox version]

[image: Chrome version]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is exactly as you described your question: The standard GWT [`ListBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html) is rendering different across browsers.

The main reason is that it is using a native browser control under the hood.
It creates a [HTML select control](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element [here](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.java#L126).
You can try that basic HTML control yourself in different browsers [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select).

So there is not much you can do about that.
On some browser you might be able to style it, but not consistently.

Comment: This actually makes sense, thank you for pointing out the under the hood issue

Answer (score 5):

First, you should use `addStyleNames` instead of `styleName`, because `styleName` removes all existing style names and replaces them with the style name you provided.

Second, this is not a GWT problem. Browsers render various elements differently. If you want a more uniform look, you need to search for CSS suggestions.

Comment: styleName and addStyleNames are used in different contexts of the application, the former being used in the core framework, the latter being used in the specific implementation of that framework

Comment: And it does strike me as a GWT issue, provided bootstrap CSS classes are browser independent and behave as such in other languages, not so in GWT

Comment: That is because a bootstrap listBox does not use a html <select> element.
A bootstrap listBox is just something that looks and behaves like a select. But in fact is no select.

Just look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select to see that a standard html select (what GWT uses) is rendered different on all browsers.

Comment: `styleName and addStyleNames are used in different contexts of the application` ???   These are two equal methods used in GWT from day one - one replaces all styles and the other adds a new style to the existing list.

Comment: If you want a consistent look and feel, take a look at gwt-material.

Comment: Yes @AndreiVolgin, we have a core framework from which all different applications feed, this is where we set the basic style of the widgets-composites with styleName, and on each individual implementation we may need to tweak that, so we do it with addStyleNames

Comment: I remember going through gwt-material some time ago, but it was in my first few weeks and didn't really have the skills to implement it, I should try that again, thanks!